# Error when trying to connect the controller class to javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

If i compile my controller and main class for my javafx project, they both compile without any errors and if I run the main class the Javafx (the GUI that I built in scene-builder) will pop-up like it is supposed to if the controller is not connected to the javafx. As soon as I try to connect the controller java file to the javafx through scene builder and then try to run the project, the GUI will not popup and it will give me this list of errors:

```
    C:\Users\Kenny's\Desktop\Project3>java Project3
    Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
     /C:/Users/Kenny's/Desktop/Project3/Project3.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at Project3.start(Project3.java:12)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javafx.scene.control.ComboBox field Project3Controller.location to java.net.URL
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(FXMLLoader.java:1163)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2554)
    ... 17 more
    Exception running application Project3

    C:\Users\Kenny's\Desktop\Project3>
```

I have tried to find a solution and I have tried it with a completely blank controller class and everything and it still does not work.
Anyone know any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, this is a bit evil.

When the FXML file is loaded, as you know, it injects fields annotated with `@FXML` in the controller with the elements with corresponding `fx:id` attributes (the attribute value in the FXML file matching the field name in the controller).

What is little known (and undocumented) is that there are a small number of (well, two) additional values that can be injected. For example, you can do

```
@FXML
private ResourceBundle resources ;
```

to get a reference to the resource bundle provided to the `FXMLLoader`. Similarly, you can get a reference to the URL provided to the `FXMLLoader` with (you guessed it):

```
@FXML
private URL location ;
```

These happen automatically.

So, it looks from the stack trace that you have a `ComboBox` defined in your FXML file and controller which you called `location`:

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> location ;
```

When the FXML loader sees this, possibly before it even tries to parse the FXML file, it tries to inject the URL provided to the loader into the field, and of course fails because it's trying to assign a `URL` to a `ComboBox`.

To fix, just change the name of the combo box:

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> locationCombo ;
```

and similarly for the `fx:id` attribute in your FXML file.

Comment: thank you very much! I just went in and changed all the fx:id's of the combo boxes and updated the controller and it now works!

Comment: Please mark the question as correct: it will help others find it if they encounter the same thing (and, as I indicated, it would be *very* hard to figure out unless you had quite a lot of experience with JavaFX).